# Bash one-liner to return substring

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

My string is:

```
 PING google.com (216.58.217.206) 56(84) bytes of data. --- google.com ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.258/4.532/4.907/0.274 ms
```

I want to return the 0 in the 0%.

The problem is this string is of variable length, but there is only one percent character. I am trying to retrieve the integer (or decimal) value of the packet loss when I have this string in a bash variable.

I have tried with cut and awk, but I am racking my brain on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the value for demonstration purposes: use a regular expression and capture the digits before the percent sign

```
$ str=' PING google.com ... 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 42% packet ...'

$ [[ $str =~ ([0-9]+)% ]] && num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

$ echo $num
42
```

using GNU grep using perl-compatible regex:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+(?=%)' <<<"$str"
42
```

Answer (score 2):

with `sed`

```
sed -r 's/.*\b([0-9]+)%.*/\1/' <<< $str
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is same as shown sample then following may help you.

```
awk '{print $18+0}' Input_file
```